# How to read file within archives?

Tags: c++

How to read file names present with an archive? (for example: .img)
I have tried the below code but it still outputs the name of the first file.

```
bool ReadFile(char* file, std::string& name)
{
    Header header;
    std::fstream file;
    file.open(file, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&header), sizeof(Header));
        file.seekg(sizeof(Header) + 4, file.cur);
        std::string vertemp(header.name, 22);
        name = vertemp;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think It would be safe to use a library. Do you mean reading files in a compressed zip or ISO files when you say archives?

Comment: yes, how to read the names of other files present within them?

Answer (score 7):

It would be impractical to write another library that can read the archive files from from scratch. Why reinvent the wheel?. I will try and give you as much information as I can for you to do what you want.

## Using libarchive

There's a great little library called libarchive written in C. It is capable of reading almost every sort of archive file you can think of, just to name a few here's what they say on their site:

> Reads a variety of formats, including tar, pax, cpio, zip, xar, lha,
> ar, cab, mtree, rar, and ISO images.

### Installing libarchive

Before you can begin using libarchive you will need to install it on your computer. If you are using a debian base OS then you are lucky otherwise you might have to search for the library in your given distribution's package repository. Alternatively you can follow the documentation on the website which will show you how to [install](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/BuildInstructions) the library from source. Open your terminal and enter the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install libarchive-dev
```

## Sample program

This little example will print the names of the contents including the complete path of the files within an archive.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <archive.h>
#include <archive_entry.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct archive *a;
    struct archive_entry *entry;
    int r;

    a = archive_read_new();
    archive_read_support_filter_all(a);
    archive_read_support_format_all(a);
    r = archive_read_open_filename(a, argv[1], 10240); // Note 1
    if (r != ARCHIVE_OK)
      return 1;
    while (archive_read_next_header(a, &entry) == ARCHIVE_OK) {
      cout << archive_entry_pathname(entry) << endl;
      archive_read_data_skip(a);
    }
    r = archive_read_free(a); 
    if (r != ARCHIVE_OK)
      return 1;

}`
```

#### Compiling and running the program

*I've saved the code above in archivereader.cpp*

1. `c++ archivereader.cpp -l archive -o archivereader`
2. `archivereader Ubuntu.iso`

## Notes

There's more to this library though then I have demonstrated.

#### More Examples

There's a tone of good information on this git page: https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples

#### Official libarchive website

The official website includes useful links to documentations and also the source code.

http://www.libarchive.org/

Comment: Can you please show the example without using libarchive?

Comment: You should read his answer instead of looking at the code only.

Comment: I think it would take 1,000 lines of C/C++ code to just to demonstrate that. Archive files have complicated structures which require specialized code to read their content. I apologize If I didn't properly answer your question. I would encourage you to look into libarchive, or read their code so you could use bits and pieces from it, If your intent is to write a custom archive reader.